# Launching vim from python in a new terminal and waiting for it to close

Tags: python, linux, vim, terminator

I am trying to create a python script that

1. Launches a new terminal window (in my case terminator)
2. Open vim on a temporary or designated  file
3. Waits until vim/terminator is closed
4. Assigns the contents of the file to a variable

Here is what I have so far:

```
import  os, subprocess

def print_tmp(i):
    with open(str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/tmp.tex'), 'r') as g:
        return print('flag ' + str(i) + ': ' + str(g.read()))

tmpfile=str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'/tmp.tex')
f = open(tmpfile,'w+')
f.write('$$')
f.close()

vimcmd = str("/usr/bin/terminator -g  ~/.config/terminator/config -p nord --geometry 60x5+0-0 -T popup-bottom-center -e \'vim " + str(tmpfile) +"\'")

print_tmp(1)
subprocess.Popen(vimcmd,shell=True).wait()
print_tmp(2)
contents=""

with open(tmpfile, 'r') as g:
    contents = g.read().strip()
print('contents = '+str(contents))
```

This opens vim on the file that I wanted just as I need. However, after calling my `vimcmd`, the script does not wait like I need it to. The variable `contents` stays as '$$'and finishes the script. How do I make python wait for the terminator window to close? By the way, I've already tried `subprocess.run()` and `subprocess.call()` but neither works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not launching Vim, you are launching Terminator.

Comment: What is your usecase for opening vim?

Answer (score 0):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
from pathlib import Path

file = Path('/tmp/myfile.txt')

os.system( 'terminator --command="vim {}"'.format( str(file.absolute()) ) ) 

myvar = None

with file.open('r') as f:
    myvar = f.readlines()

print(myvar)
```